# Qt - How to dynamically insert Qml objects from C++ class

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquickcontrols, qqmlcontext

I need an advice about my simple **QT/QML** application.

I have the following situation:

about the interface, I have a main area called 'flickableArea' (flickableArea.qml) divided into four areas (item **slot1**, item **slot2**, item **slot3** and item **slot4**).

Each slot is filled with QML Rectangle object.

**slot1** filled by rectangle with id=**area1**, **slot2** filled by rectangle with id=**area2**, **slot3** filled by rectangle with id=**area3**, **slot4** filled by rectangle with id=**area4**

FILE **flickableArea.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Item {

    property alias mainGrid: mainGrid
    property alias slot1: slot1
    property alias slot2: slot2
    property alias slot3: slot3
    property alias slot4: slot4

    id: flickableAreaItem
    width: 600
    height: 300

    Flickable {
        id: flickableArea
        boundsBehavior: Flickable.DragOverBounds
        interactive: true
        flickableDirection: Flickable.HorizontalFlick
        anchors.fill: parent

        GridLayout {
            id: mainGrid
            columnSpacing: 3
            rowSpacing: 3
            rows: 2
            columns: 2
            anchors.fill: parent

            Item {
                id: slot1
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: false
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }

            Item {
                id: slot2
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: false
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }

            Item {
                id: slot3
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: false
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }

            Item {
                id: slot4
                Layout.fillWidth: true
                Layout.fillHeight: true
                clip: false
                Rectangle {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    border.width: 1
                    border.color: "black"
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I should insert dynamically QML objects in **area1**, **area2**, **area3** and **area4** when a defined signal is triggered in the c++ code.
On c++ code, when the signal is triggered, I run the following code to create a new object (ObjectToIntroduce) connected to Object.qml:

```
ObjectToIntroduce *obj;
obj = new ObjectToIntroduce();
QQmlContext *objContext = engine->rootContext();
objContext->setContextProperty("obj", obj);
```

After I have made a new ObjectToIntroduce how can I introduce/destroy (view/hide) Object.qml in area1/area2/area3/area4 of flickableArea.qml?

I want to know what is the best way to implement this mechanism, to writing this simple Qt/Qml application.
Thanks in advice, best regards

Lele

Comment: why cant you use  "Connections" in qml and "target" as obj, then handle hide/show in the connection slot ."http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html"

Comment: Creating QML components in C++ isn't good practice. Instead of that you can implement your own component derived from `QQuickItem` and so create it in QML in regular way. As for your question, you should provide more code. What is `ObjectToIntroduce`?

Comment: ObjectToIntroduce is a simple c++ class that have Q_PROPERTY (for example const QString) connected to the Object.qml. I should insert this Object.qml in flickableArea.qml when the signal is triggered in the c++ code. Thanks

Comment: For example I can create a QQmlComponent from c++ code, but I don't know how load this component in other qml object.